# Given a spouse ID, how do you append spouse data to a subject's data row in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am working with a survey dataset where each row is a subject/observation. In one of the data columns I have an entry with the spouse ID. I want to add the spouse level of education (i.e. a data entry from the spouse's row) to that of the other spouse's observation--any suggestions on how I can do this in Stata?

Comment: For future questions, please post Stata code and why it's not working for you, therefore proving you have spent time and effort researching your problem. Questions asking only for code are condiered by many to be off-topic.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers as you have at this moment a few questions with answers, that have not received any noticeable feedback on your behalf.

Comment: @Roberto I see your point, and agree. Will try to provide more info code/data structure in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found `merge`, when comparing when other strategies, to be quite efficient; so Maarten's answer is probably the best option. But here I show another way of doing it: looping over observations (incidently, in less than a week, this question or a variant thereof has appeared at least three times between statalist.org and StackOverflow).

```
clear all
set more off

* ----- example data -----

input id spid educ // from maarten buis
      1  2    6
      2  1    12 
      3  6    10
      4  5    13
      5  4    6
end

list, sep(0)

*----- what you want -----

gen speduc = .
forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
    replace speduc = educ[`i'] if id[`i'] == spid
}

list, sep(0)
```

Comment: @Maarten's and Aspen's answers were very helpful too, but this one work the best in my case. Will be more clear about the actual data structure in future posts since some of these issues probably come from the fact that the data I have groups entire families into households (i.e. besides your spouse you will also be grouped with your children), and within each household the subjects' have IDs that are repeated across different households.

Answer (score 1):

```
// create some example data
clear
input id spid educ
      1  2    6
      2  1    12 
      3  6    10
      4  5    13
      5  4    6
end

// create temporary file
tempfile original_data
save `original_data'

// prepare new file for merging
drop id
rename spid id
rename educ speduc

// merge
merge 1:1 id using `original_data'

// admire the result
list

// the master file is actually the file you created
// so you probably don't want to observations who only come from master
// _merge == 1
drop if _merge == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maarten's solution is really neat and efficient. Here's an alternative without using `merge`. The benefit is that it creates an ID variable for each couple.

```
clear
// create some data and include cases without matches
input ID SPO_ID EDU
1 5 12
2 4 16
3 . 12
4 2 18
5 1 14
6 . 15
7 9 19
end
tempvar x y // unique IDs for non-missing cases
egen x=group(ID SPO_ID)
egen y=group(SPO_ID ID)
egen DYAD=rowmin(x y)       // DYAD=> ID for each couple
sort DYAD
// distinguish within each DYAD; you can use sex/gender if given and all are heterosexual marriages
by DYAD: gen DYAD_ID=_n-1 if !missing(DYAD)
gen SPO_EDU=.
replace SPO_EDU=EDU[_n+1] if (DYAD_ID==0 & DYAD[_n]==DYAD[_n+1])
replace SPO_EDU=EDU[_n-1] if (DYAD_ID==1 & DYAD[_n]==DYAD[_n-1])
list
```

This is adapted from this UCLA's idre [page](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/dyad_ids.htm).

Comment: Aspen, there's something going on here. Using Maarten's data the results differ.

Comment: Apparently it happens when there are unpaired cases with non-missing values on the spousal IDs. Thanks. I'll fix the code to account for this scenario.